# clearFocus не работает, если текст длинный

Tags: android, focus, edittext

Использую два `EditText'a`, первый для названия, второй для примечания. Установил кнопку, ко клику очищаю фокус с обоих эдитов. Если тексты маленькие и в пределах видимости, то фокусы убираются как положено. Если вставить длинный текст, или переходить на новую строку до тех пор, пока не получится скролл, фокус уже не убирается, в чем может быть причина такого поведения?

Код разметки:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".AddNoteActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_note">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_add_chapter_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/chapter_title"
        android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.6dp"
        android:background="@color/main" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_add_chapter_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/chapter_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

И в активити:

```
etAddChapterTitle.clearFocus();
etAddChapterContent.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину. У второго `EditText` высота должна быть `match_parent`, но внутри `ScrollView` она не становится `match_parent`, пока в `ScrollView` не добавить `android:fillViewport="true"`.